# Mozilla Firefox browser issue

Tags: firefox

I'm using `Mozilla Firefox version 3.6.13`.

The issue is that when I try to open a web page I have to keep moving the mouse cursor for the browser to proceed with opening the page. Why is that?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried [using another profile](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_Manager) or resetting your profile? Will that make the problem disappear?

Comment: Get the Firefox 4 beta! Not only would you solve your issue (probably), but you'd be helping prevent these sort of things in the future. ;)

Comment: As MJB says - which Operating System are you running?

Comment: @Linker3000. Thanks for your reply. I'm using `Windows 7 Enterprise`.

Comment: @slhck. Thanks for your reply. No really, I didn't try that.

Comment: It's been the main source of problems for me, most of the times. Please see what you can do and then update your question with some details.

Comment: Can you still reproduce this issue or is it not a problem anymore?

Answer (score 0):

In the good ole days, I'd wonder whether the serial port/mouse adaptor was trying to share an interrupt with the network interface card. For you youngsters, the equivalent might be - try the mouse in a different USB port (if it's in a USB port and not a PS/2 mouse).

Thinking laterally, I'd perhaps restart the PC, press F2, DEL..whatever... to enter the BIOS setup program and make sure that the BIOS knows you have a 'plug and play' (PnP) operating system and/or try resetting the PCI/PnP configuration data if you have such an option.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm actually using a `laptop', and there are no mouses attached, just using the laptop pad.